# the non generic type cannot be used with type arguments (Realm Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, realm

I decided to use Realm database for xamarin ios

I need to get a response from  API and write to database data from it.

Here is a method for getting data from API

```
 public async Task<string> Logining(string email, string password)
    {
        string result;
        var client = new RestClient("http://api.xplorpal.com");
        var request = new RestRequest("/login", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("email", email);
        request.AddParameter("password", password);
        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        var content = response.Content;
        if (content.Length > 100)
        {
            try
            {
                var usr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(content);
                var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
                realm.Write(() =>
                {
                    var mydog = realm.CreateObject<UserModel>();

                });

            }
            catch 
            { 
            }
            result = "Authorized";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Auth problem" + content;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

At this line I want to write data to realm database

```
 var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
                realm.Write(() =>
                {
                    var mydog = realm.CreateObject<UserModel>();

                });
```

But I get error

> the non-generic type cannot be used with type arguments (string, object)

But I do all like in docs

[Realm Docs](https://realm.io/blog/introducing-realm-xamarin/)

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing an old Realm blog post and the API has been changed since then (2016).

Instead of using `CreateObject` directly, you can create the RealmObject subclass, assign its properties and then add it to your Realm instance:

```
var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
var mydog = new UserModel
{
   // Set your properties...
};
realm.Write(() => realm.Add(mydog));
```

I would recommend referring to the .Net Realm docs directly:

- https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest

The newer version of `CreateObject` method returns a "dynamic" object and creates a "placeholder" in the Realm instance based upon the primary key that you provide:

```
var dynObj = realm.CreateObject(typeof(UserModel).FullName, "somePIKey");
```

Comment: @EugeneSukh ;-) The API for .Net Realm went through a number of large changes before stabilizing in the 1.x branch (I still have an app on `v0.6` due to the huge changes made to .Net Realm after that and the refactoring is too involved to port it to the latest version...)